# How to bind CollectionViewSource to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, collectionview, collectionviewsource

I have a datagrid and want to bind its item source  as CollectionViewSource which has the source of List. But binding is not working. Please check my code in below. Note that i dont want to use ObservableCollection because of virtualization problem while grouping.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="weightItemCollection" Source="{Binding Path=LoadCaseWeightItems}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LocalizedGroupName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="LocalizedGroupName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid  x:Name="customLoadCaseGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource weightItemCollection}}" />
```

User Control code

```
public partial class WeightItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   List<WeightItemData> loadCaseWeightItems;
  public List<WeightItemData> LoadCaseWeightItems { get { return loadCaseWeightItems; } set { loadCaseWeightItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LoadCaseWeightItems)); } }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  
   public WeightItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadCaseWeightItems = new List<WeightItemData>();
        //Here i add items to loadCaseWeightItems 
    }

  
  
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: It should be `{Binding LoadCaseWeightItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`. Besides that, consider making `LoadCaseWeightItems` a dependency property to make it bindable.

Comment: Could you write how to make LoadCaseWeightItems  as dependency property ?

Comment: There are hundreds of examples on the internet, also here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Should i make <CollectionViewSource x:Key="weightItemCollection" Source="{Binding LoadCaseWeightItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"> and also make LoadCaseWeightItems as dependency property ?

Comment: When i do the first one, i got the exception : {"Unexpected record in Baml stream.  Trying to add to Binding which is not a collection or has a TypeConverter."} in the line of DataGrid which sets ItemSource  as ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource weightItemCollection}}"

Comment: @nihasmata you can edit your question to add more details if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="weightItemCollection"
                          Source="{Binding Path=LoadCaseWeightItems,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="LocalizedGroupName"/>
         </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="LocalizedGroupName"/>
         </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="customLoadCaseGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource weightItemCollection}}" />
</Grid>
```

You may also set the `Source` programmatically:

```
public WeightItem()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadCaseWeightItems = ...;

    ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["weightItemCollection"]).Source = loadCaseWeightItems;
}
```